# List items 3 by 3 on SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have my class observer.data with all my data inside in an array, and I would like to List only 3 per 3.

Exemple: the list should display the items 3 by 3: [0], [3], [6], [9]... 
**and should not display** [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]

My code is like :

```
List(observer.data){ i in
   card(name: i.name token: i.token)
}
```

SwiftUI is still an experimentation for me, thanks a lot any reply you could give me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to look at the range using the `indices` property of the array and filter on them

```
var body: some View {
    List(observer.data.indices.filter {$0 % 3 == 0}, id: \.self){ index in
        card(name: self.observer.data[index].name, token: self.observer.data[index].token
    }
}
```

If the type inside the `data` array conforms to `Hashable` the above could be written in a clearer way by first mapping the indices to the element in the array.

```
var body: some View {
    List(observer.data.indices.filter {$0 % 3 == 0}.map({observer.data[$0]}), id: \.self) { item in
        card(name: item.name, token: item.token
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your first message helped me. My array conformed to Hashable but I had to use the first one because I needed to change my id.